# Recovering tizen settings actions

Tags: tizen

I've alredy researched in tizen documentation, but it does not find anything practical.

I wonder if it is possible to retrieve settings actions, like airplane mode, in tizen?

just like android default broadcasts receives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting are generally specific to framework.

There are a few system level read only settings as well.

Refer to the Tizen developer guide.

https://developer.tizen.org/documentation/mobile-web-app-programming/programming-guide/device-api-guides/system-guides/system-information-accessing-device-specific-information

Comment: Thanks for the info, I found “isFlightMode”.
I wonder if you can capture “power paving” and “do not disturb”;
The maximum I found was the battery state: SystemInfoBattery
reference: http://goo.gl/2Schuk

Comment: [Power Saving](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/device-settings-and-systems/power-states) - Web [DoNotDistrurb](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__NOTIFICATION__MODULE.html#ga4761a9c3ed02599e340a721906360f2f) - Unfortunately Native only.